# PHP merge tablerows

Tags: php, html-table

I got a table as DOMDocument which looks like this:

```
 name   | user      | comment
 -----------------------------
 Test   | user1     | Line 1
 Abc    | user2     | Line 1
        |           | Line 2
 Test2  | user3     | Line 1
 Test3  | user3     | Line 1
        |           | Line 2
        |           | Line 3
```

as you can see, sometimes the comment Wraps over multiple tablerows. (Apparently when the comment is a long one)
When those wraps occur, all fields except for the comment one are empty.

How can I merge those wrapped comments together and output them?

I am currently outputting them like this:

```
foreach ($xml->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $row) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($row->getElementsByTagName('td') as $column) {
            echo "<td>" . $column->textContent . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are outputting each row before you know what the next one contains. A different approach would be to store each row in an array, allowing you to correct the previous row if the following row meets a certain condition (eg. wrapping). You can then output the resulting array as an HTML table once processed.

Something like this (untested):

```
// build array
$rows = array();
$xmlRows = $xml->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
foreach ($xmlRows as $xmlRow) {
    $emptyFields = 0;
    $row = array();
    $xmlColumns = $xmlRow->getElementsByTagName('td');
    foreach ($xmlColumns as $xmlColumn) {
        if (empty($xmlColumn->textContent)) { // count empty fields
            $emptyFields++;
        }
        $row[] = $xmlColumn->textContent;
    }
    if ($emptyFields >= 2) { // detect if wrapping has occurred
        $lastRow = array_pop($rows); // remove last row from array
        $lastRow[2] .= $row[2]; // update last row with wrapped data
        $row = $lastRow; // use newly merged row
    }
    $rows[] = $row;
}
// output array
foreach ($rows as &$row) {
    $row = '<td>' . implode('</td><td>', $row) . '</td>';
}
echo '<table><tr>' . implode('</tr><tr>', $rows) . '</tr></table>';
```

Comment: I changed `(boolean)$wrapped` to `(int)$emptyFields` because it wrapped already when only one of the columns were empty. But in my case all but the last one had to be empty for the wrapping. Now it is working like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem - glad it works for you. I've merged your (rejected) suggested edits into my answer.

Comment: Thanks :-) Using `array_pop` is a really elegant solution in my opinion. Good idea.